# Operand type clash date is incompatible with int

Tags: mysql, sql

```
SELECT 'fields'INTO #MONTHS 
FROM 'table_name'
WHERE 'field_name' BETWEEN @FROM AND @TO
```

'field_Name', `@from` and `@TO` are DATETIME values.

Comment: The single quotes around the column names seem wrong.  Did you mean to use backticks? Is it just a typo for the question post?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.